# How do kernel, driver writers find the header files to include?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, header-files

For example in linux-6.15.68 drivers/pci/endpoint/pci-epc-mem.c, there is this line in function pci_epc_mem_alloc_addr.

```
align_size = ALIGN(size, mem->window.page_size);
```

To be able to use macro 'ALIGN', this file should include a header file defining 'ALIGN'.
Using ctags, I can see 'ALIGN' is defined in include/linux/aligh.h but this file (pci-epc-mem.c) only includes 4 files as below.

```
#include <linux/io.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

#include <linux/pci-epc.h>
```

Of course header files include other header files so one (or some) of these files must have eventually had the line '#include <linux/align.h>. So I guess the linux kernel or driver writers will include the most releavant(having the least common set of definitions) and top-most header file needed. How do they find it? Do they just use search? (For example search for '#include <linux/aligh.h>' and search up..) or are they well aware of the header files hiearchy?

Comment: I suppose you could look at the blame for this specific file and ask whoever first used the `ALIGN` macro why they included the header files as shown. I think without that it's reasonable to assume that someone working on a complex system has some idea of which header files are needed for which macros.

Comment: It's also possible that during development they would spam all possible headers and do an explicit cleanup phase before publishing the patch. An incremental build of the kernel is reasonably fast, so you just comment the headers one by one and rebuild...

Comment: There is no harm in driver source including `<linux/align.h>` explicitly, and that is probably recommended for new kernel code. The stuff in `<linux/align.h>` was factored out of `<linux/kernel.h>` in v5.13 so it is a relatively recent split. (Factoring various stuff out of `<linux/kernel.h>` into new headers is an ongoing process.) Third-party out-of-tree drivers should check the kernel version before including it.